# Are @UseFilters() actually necessary?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

So I have a regular Global Exceptions filter just like the one on the [NestJS docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters), and altough it works for most of exceptions, I had to create a new one for KafkaJS exceptions, like on the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/exception-filters) too.

My question is: Do I need to use the `@UseFilters()` decorator for it to work? Because right now, I can't make it work if I'm not using it directly above my controller... Can I make it global?

Comment: if it's global, then `@UseFilters` will be useless

Comment: @MicaelLevi But it's exactly what I need to find out... My global filter only catches HTTP errors, so I need to use that one the microservices doc, as I mentioned.

I just don't know how to do it globally